# Assigning namespace variables inside of a function

Tags: r, namespaces

I'm struggling to assign a namespace variable inside of a function. Consider this example using the CRAN package "qcc":  `qcc()` generates a plot, but 
the display options of that plot are controlled by `qcc.options()`.

When working in global, everything is fine:

```
library(qcc)
qcc.options(bg.margin="red")        # sets margin background colour, i.e.
                                    # qcc:::.qcc.options$bg.margin is "red"
qcc(rnorm(100), type = "xbar.one")  # generates a plot with red margin
```

But when working in the local environment of a function, `qcc` and `qcc.options` seem to use the namespace differently:

```
foo <- function(x){
   qcc.options(bg.margin=x)
   qcc(rnorm(100), type = "xbar.one")
}

foo("green")  # generates a default plot with grey margins
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because of where `qcc.options` stores its `.qcc.options` variable. Working in global, this is `qcc:::.qcc.options`, but when you're inside a function, it is storing it in a local variable just called `.qcc.options`, thus when you try to use `plot.qcc` (called by `qcc`) it retrieves options from the global (non-exported) `qcc:::.qcc.options` rather than the local `.qcc.options`.

Here's a function that shows what's happening with the options:

```
bar <- function(x){
   pre <- qcc:::.qcc.options
   pre.marg <- qcc.options("bg.margin")
   qcc.options(bg.margin=x)
   post1 <- qcc:::.qcc.options
   post2 <- .qcc.options
   post.marg <- qcc.options("bg.margin")
   qcc(rnorm(100), type = "xbar.one")
   list(pre,post1,post2,pre.marg,post.marg)
}
bar('green')
```

If you look at the results, you'll see that `qcc.options` creates the local variable and changes its value of `bg.margin` to `"green"` but this isn't the object that's subsequently referenced by `plot.qcc`.

Seems like you should request some code modifications from the package maintainer because this is probably not the best setup.

EDIT: A workaround is to use `assignInNamespace` to use the local variable to overwrite the global one. (Obviously, this then changes the parameter globally and would affect all subsequent plots unless the parameter is updated.)

```
foo <- function(x){
   qcc.options(bg.margin=x)
   assignInNamespace('.qcc.options',.qcc.options,ns='qcc')
   qcc(rnorm(100), type = "xbar.one")
}
foo('green')
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Thomas! I knew what was happening, I just didn't know how to assign the variable correctly. `assignInNamespace` does the job just fine.

Comment: @user2853399 Sounds good. I would definitely mention it to the package maintainer, though, because you shouldn't have to make that step (since it's not obvious what `qcc.options` is actually doing).

Comment: I sent an email to the maintainer with a link to this page just after I got the answer :)  Thank you again!

Answer (score 4):

Here is an ugly hack:

```
foo <- function(x){
  old.qcc.options <- get(".qcc.options", asNamespace("qcc"))
  assign(".qcc.options", qcc.options(bg.margin=x), asNamespace("qcc"))
  res <- qcc(rnorm(100), type = "xbar.one")
  assign(".qcc.options", old.qcc.options, asNamespace("qcc"))
  invisible(res)
}

foo("green")
```

Of course, the scoping issues would be better solved by changing `qcc.options`. You should contact the package maintainer about that.

Comment: Thank you very much, Roland! This is basically a similar workaround as proposed by Thomas, just setting the original options back, after usage (good point). I have already mailed the package mantainers. Thanks again, the hack is just perfect for me.